# restore with AWS EBS' snapshots on separate cluster

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

I have a cluster with 3 nodes - say cluster1 on AWS EC2 instances. The cluster is up and running, took snapshot of the keyspace's volume.

Now I want to restore few tables/keyspaces from the snapshot volumes, so I created another cluster say cluster2 and attached the snapshot volumes on to the new cluster's ec2 nodes (same number of nodes). Cluster2 is not starting bcz the system keyspace in the snapshot taken was having cluster name as cluster1 and the cluster on which it is being restored is cluster2. How do I do a restore in this case? I do not want to do any modifications to the existing cluster.

Also when I do restore do I need to think about the token ranges of the old and new cluster's mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before starting the cluster2, it's important to ensure that none of the IP addresses of the cluster1 are included in the seed list of the cluster2 to ensure that they are kept unaware between them. Also, to remove from the path `data_file_directories` (as defined in the cassandra.yaml), the following directories:

- system
- system_auth
- system_distributed
- system_traces

**`system_schema` should not be touched, as it contains the schema definition of the keyspaces and tables.**

Start the cluster, one node at a time; the first node should include its own IP address at the beginning of the seed list; This will be a one time change, and the change should be removed once that the cluster is up and running.

At this moment you should have a separate cluster, with the information and structure of the original cluster at the time that the snapshot was taken. To test this, execute `nodetool gossipinfo` and only the nodes of the cluster2 should be listed, login into cqlsh `describe keyspaces` should list all your keyspaces, and executing queries of your application should retrieve your data. You will note that Cassandra already generated the system* keyspaces, as well as dealt with the token distribution.

The next step is to update the name of the restored cluster, in each one of the nodes:

1. Log into cqlsh
2. Execute `UPDATE system.local SET cluster_name = 'cluster2' where key='local';`
3. exit cqlsh
4. run `nodetool flush`
5. run `nodetool drain`
6. edit the cassandra.yaml file, update `cluster_name` with the name 'cluster2'
7. restart the cassandra service
8. wait until the node is reported as NORMAL with `nodetool status` or `nodetool netstats`
9. repeat with a different node

At this point you will have 2 independent clusters, with different name.